# Is unsubscribing in subscribe a good practice?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I encountered next piece of code. It's an Angular component:

```js
private initializeSubscription?: Subscription;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initializeSubscription = this.solutionRuntimeChangedEvents.onEvent().subscribe({
    next: (): void => {
      this.initializeSubscription?.unsubscribe(); // is this here ok?
      this.initialize();
    }
  });
}
```

Can this introduce any potential bugs or weird behaviour? My first thought is that it must be a better way.

Comment: Seems like the author didn't know they could just ask for the [`first`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/first) emitted value.

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with what you're doing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's why I asked the question, so other people can remind of first. I see nothing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

As one comment suggests, using the `first()` operator will emit the first received value, then complete. When an observable completes, any subscribers will automatically unsubscribe.

With this in mind, you code can be refactored as follows:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.solutionRuntimeChangedEvents.onEvent().pipe(
    first(),
    tap(_=>this.initialize())
  ).subscribe();
}
```

The `tap()` operator should be used to invoke any side effects, which in this case is your `initialize()` method.